# Allowing 0.0.0.0 access in WAMP

Tags: apache, wamp

Everything is setup correctly, but I'm getting "403..... Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server." error's when I access my IP address or my TLD. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your VirtualHost, make sure that you have access permissions set in the Directory block...

```
order allow,deny
allow from all
```

Check your DocumentRoot folder for an .htaccess file, it can override the above.

Aside from that, you can also get this error when your VirtualHost does not contain the proper ServerName or ServerAlias and the request ends up falling into the default httpd.conf setup.

Also consider trying out another WAMP package.

[xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) (free) -
[WampDeveloper Pro](http://www.devside.net/server/webdeveloper) (commercial) -
[WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (free)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably making requests from `::1`, which is IP6 `127.0.0.1`.

So just update your `<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">` section at `C:\wamp\bin\apache\ApacheX.X.X\conf\httpd.conf` sections to:

```
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1
```

Remember to also do it in all conf files of `C:\wamp\alias`

This way you preserve the apache security.